# Pythagorean triplets

Tags: java, optimization, mathematics

This code is about finding Pythagorean triplets.  I take a number as input, and find from 1 to that number, how many Pythagorean triplets exist.

Are there ways this can be optimized? It takes a lot of time, but actually doesn't only provide the output for `no` > 10000

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Solution
{

BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
HashMap<Integer,Set<Set<Integer>>> mymap=new HashMap<Integer,Set<Set<Integer>>>();
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Solution s=new Solution();
    try
    {
        int t=Integer.parseInt(s.in.readLine());
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
            {
                int no=Integer.parseInt(s.in.readLine());
                s.findAllPythogoreanTriplets(no);
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
public void findAllPythogoreanTriplets(int no) {


    if(mymap.containsKey(new Integer(no)))
        System.out.println(mymap.get(no).size());
    else
    {
    int [] unsortedData=new int[no];
    for(int i=0;i<no;i++)
        unsortedData[i]=i+1;
// O(n) - Square all the elements in the array
for (int i = 0; i < unsortedData.length; i++)
    unsortedData[i] *= unsortedData[i];

// O(n logn) - Sort
int [] sortedSquareData = unsortedData;

// O(n2)
Set<Set<Integer>> triplets = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();

for (int i = 0; i < sortedSquareData.length; i++) {

    Set<Set<Integer>> pairs = findAllPairsThatSumToAConstant(sortedSquareData, sortedSquareData[i]);

    for (Set<Integer> pair : pairs) {
        Set<Integer> triplet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (Integer n : pair) {
            triplet.add((int)Math.sqrt(n));
        }
        triplet.add((int)Math.sqrt(sortedSquareData[i])); // adding the third element to the pair to make it a triplet
        triplets.add(triplet);
    }
}
mymap.put(no,triplets);
System.out.println(triplets.size());
}

}


public Set<Set<Integer>> findAllPairsThatSumToAConstant(int [] sortedData, int constant) {

// O(n)
Set<Set<Integer>> pairs = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
int p1 = 0; // pointing to the first element
int p2 = sortedData.length - 1; // pointing to the last element
while (p1 < p2) {
    int pointersSum = sortedData[p1] + sortedData[p2];
    if (pointersSum > constant)
        p2--;
    else if (pointersSum < constant)
        p1++;
    else {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        set.add(sortedData[p1]);
        set.add(sortedData[p2]);
        pairs.add(set);
        p1++;
        p2--;
    }
}
return pairs;
 }
 }
```

Comment: ohk see the code is about finding pythagorean triplets,so i take a no as input,and find from 1 to that no,how many pythagorean triplets exist.I am uploading the code,now,pls see,if u can optimize it

Comment: Note that your imported code has nothing to do with the original question. The code has no long values at all. I am somewhat confused about that relationship, but, the code, in its current format is much more on-topic.

Comment: yes because after your previous comment,i changes all long to in,dats y it appears that it has no significance to what i had posted before.

Answer (score 3):

I will not start about optimatization but I'll do first a review so you could write better code and can post it again in a new question.

Take [a look at this code in the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/49048/35389).
That question is a vey nice example of understandable coding.

### No logic in static void main (String args[])

Your main method may only do :

- Init of your initials vars.
- Call your class for solution.
- Print out the result.

I see multiple times call to your Solution class.
This is possible when you want to ask multiple cases, but al least in the for-loop there must be a printout of the result.

### Class should return solution of your problem.

Your method `public void findAllPythogoreanTriplets(int no)` should return the solution of the problem.
Your method is void so you can never output your solution.(keep in mind previous comment).
The method should be :

```
public set<PythogoreanTriplet> findAllPythogoreanTriplets (Set<Integer>)
```

I should create a basic Pojo class for a triplet.
The `Set<Integer>` as parameter is up to discussion, you could use a `List`, `Iterable`, `Collection` or just an array.

### Naming of variables, methods and class.

What a name is `Solution` for a class?
How do you know what it does?
What about `PythagoreanTripletsFinder` as class name?

Same for vars :

```
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
```

`i` you could define as `counter`, `t` you could define as `maxLinesToRead`.

### Formatting of code

If you use a more intelligent IDE you can do an autoformat of code.
This increase the readability of the code.
For netbeans : <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
For eclipse : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

### Smaller methods equals lesser complexity

You have 2 methods for the whole problem solution.
Complexity is very high for each method.

Your comments are already set on a nice place to extract that little piece of code to an extra method.
Also same with if - else.
The code in the braces in the if you could extract to a method (of course when its more then one line), the same for the else condition.

### Always use braces

```
for(int i=0;i<no;i++)
    unsortedData[i]=i+1;
```

should be :

```
for(int i=0;i<no;i++) {
    unsortedData[i]=i+1;
}
```

It's clearder to see what you want to do with the for.
On the other hand searching a bug is also faster when you always set braces.

### Scoping global variables

```
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
HashMap<Integer,Set<Set<Integer>>> mymap=new HashMap<Integer,Set<Set<Integer>>>();
```

They are now `package private`.
I don't have something against `package private` scope but **always** make your global variables `private` and make them accesible outside the class with getters and/or setters.
No one will ask if it is your intention when you make a method `package private` cause almost nobody makes that fault, while on the other hand a lot of people forget to scope the global variables.

so it should be :

```
private BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
private HashMap<Integer,Set<Set<Integer>>> mymap=new HashMap<Integer,Set<Set<Integer>>>();
```

In your example I don't think you need getters/setters for outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Euclid's formula to find the triplets. This formula says that the triplet (a, b, c) can be generated by using two integer m and n, where a = 2mn, b = m^2 - n^2, and c = m^2 + n^2. For example,

```
int max = 1000000;
for (int m = 1; m*m <= max; m++) {
  for (int n = 1; n <= m && (m*m) + (n*n) <= max; n++) {
    int a = 2*m*n;
    int b = m*m - n*n;
    int c = m*m + n*n;
    // print a, b, and c
  }
}
```

The algorithm above produces duplicate triplets (e.g., (3, 4, 5) and (4, 3, 5)). But, it we can easily add a check to prevent this problem. I will leave it to you to figure out.